# how to solve that buttom navigation bar doesn't appear in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

First,, Thanks for answering of questions about flutter in everytime.

As explaining the way this time, I tried to make that seperating button navigation bar as a widget in another file from main file and try to use it in main file like below. but it doesn't appear and not specific error.. so I don't get why is it not apper and how to use this in the way that I tried to? Could you give me some advice about this? Thanks a lot.

--main page I used--

```
return Scaffold(
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
```

--bottomNavigationBar widget page--

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {

  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    HomePage(),
    ShopPage(),
    PeoplePage(),
    WalletPage()
  ];
  
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  Widget currentScreen = HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:  PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = HomePage();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Home',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = ShopPage();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shop,
                          color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Shop',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Right Tab Bar Icons
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = WalletPage();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.wallet,
                          color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Home',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = PeoplePage();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.people,
                          color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Shop',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do? Can you share some screenshots of what is happening and what is expected!?

Comment: why there are 2 Scaffolds? that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to the fact that your BottomBar class' build method contains a Scaffold and it should not. It should only return a BottomAppBar widget. You can move all of your FAB widget code to the outer scaffold in your Main Page class.